# Laravel Pusher uses old apikey only in aws -> how can I clear/ change it?

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-5, amazon-ec2, pusher

I have an angular & laravel app that uses pusher.
I changed the apiKey, secret etc in the .env in laravel.
**It works well on local** but when I try on AWS EC2 the credentials are still the old ones:

```
$config = config('broadcasting.connections.pusher');
   dd($config) // gives old credentials only in staging/aws
```

I tried all the clearing:
cache:clear, 
route:clear,
route:cache
config:clear
config:cache
optimize,
view:clear

in the local and in the AWS-cli and it gave me the notification that everything was ok ('cleared!').

Is there a way to clear or set the .env through the AWS dashboard?

**PS - the old credentials are no where to be found in the client & back side**. Unless laravel itself is still storing the old credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the issue and turned out the .env was not updated to reflect the new keys

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I edited my question, I tried:
I tried all the clearing:
cache:clear, 
route:clear,
route:cache
config:clear
config:cache
optimize,
view:clear

Comment: No, I still get the old credentials.
Does AWS has a cache of itself for .env vars?

Comment: those are the credentials for AWS. I need to edit credentials for Pusher inside AWS if there is such option...

Comment: Pusher has nothing to do with AWS, it's just your application, maybe there is environment variable in your system

Comment: I know pusher has nothing to do with AWS
But it works in local, but doesnt work on AWS, and the I deleted the old keys from the back and client...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205154/discussion-between-aws-ps-and-dash).

Comment: hello, can you mark it as resolved, I spent a lot of time in debugging the issue

Comment: Sure! sorry for the delay